# If Then statement for the Listindex in a combobox Userform

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a Userform with 19 Checkboxes for a shift schedule. The user now chooses in every combobox the employee. Based on the index choosen, the Name, phone number and a picture of said employee should be copied into a shift schedule for later printing.
I'm trying now to make an if then statement for each combobox in order to copy the information of said employee into a preformatted shift schedule. But the problem is: no matter which index I choose only the first index is copied (here it's index 0). Can you guys see the problem?

```
Dim Ind1 As Variant
Ind1 = UserForm1.ComboBox1.ListIndex


'Select Case Ind1

'##########################################################
    
    If Ind1 = 0 Then
        
sH.Range("A4").Copy Destination:=acS.Range("F9")
Range("F9").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 14
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
End If
    
'##########################################################

If Ind1 = 1 Then
    
    sH.Range("A5").Copy Destination:=acS.Range("F9")
    
    sH.Range("C5").Copy Destination:=acS.Range("F11")
    
    Range("F9:F11").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 14
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With

End If
```

Comment: The two cases seem to copy different numbers of cells.  It's not really clear from your post what the problem is.

Comment: It would help to post more of the code, but remove the cell/font formatting parts: they're not relevant to your problem, and they're making your code too bulky and hard to follow

Comment: In order for my boss to make changes to the employees, if something changes, I made a another sheet with all employes. So lets say the user chooses the first item in the combobox (index 0). This means this shift is unoccupied. The second item is the first employee. Here I need to copy the name ("A5") and the phone number ("C5"). Thats why there are different numbers of cells to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Without any formatting:

```vb
Dim indx As Variant
indx = UserForm1.ComboBox1.ListIndex

'copy blank or employee name
sH.Range("A4").Offset(indx, 0).Copy Destination:=acS.Range("F9")

'copy phone# if there's a selected employee, else clear existing
If indx > 0 Then
    sH.Range("C4").Offset(indx, 0).Copy Destination:=acS.Range("F11")
Else
    acS.Range("F11").ClearContents
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately the code still only copies the first entry "unoccupied", even if I choose another entry in the list

Comment: Is your code looking at the right listbox?  Have you checked the value of `indx is what you expect?`

Comment: Is your code looking at the correct listbox (and the correct form)? Have you checked the value of `indx` is what you expect?